# Saving the current seed in a Fortran random number sequence

Tags: fortran, output, generator, seed

I am currently using the intrinsic function `rand()` to generate random numbers.  I initialized my sequence with some defined seed, but I want to be able to output the current seed that `rand()` is using at some point in my loop.

By doing this, I should be able to "continue" the sequence of random numbers in a new program.

From what I have seen online, there is no way to do this with the random number generator associated with `rand()` and `srand()` functions.  Is this true?  Can anyone suggest a different method (perhaps, `RANDOM_NUMBER()`?).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rand` and `srand` are not standard Fortran functions.  I expect your compiler documentation can tell you how best to use them.  However the Fortran standard defines a subroutine `random_seed` with three optional arguments (named `save`, `put` and `get`). `put` and `get` are for setting and getting the random seed.  `save` can be used to return the size of integer array used to hold the seed for the PRNG. The generator can then be called with the standard routine `random_number`.

Comment: This is true, they are GNU extensions.  I don't really know what that means - but they are not "standard".  Thanks for the advice, my only concern is that random_number is only standard for f95, but I imagine that is not a problem...

Comment: What *they are GNU extensions* means is that the GNU compiler writers thought it would be nice to give Fortrannies the use of those functions.  Other compiler writers have made other extensions to the Fortran standards in their compilers.  Your concern about `random_number` having been introduced in Fortran 90 (not 95 ?) is only valid if you are sending messages through the vortex from a time before 1995.

Comment: Haha, well then I guess it's no concern at all!  There is so little good documentation about this stuff online, I really appreciate the help.